# "some installed products need licenses. Please start automation license manager..." TIA portal installation error

Tags: installation, plc, siemens, tia-portal

Newbie here.

So I've been having trouble installing TIA Portal v15.1. During the installation, I always get an error message saying "some installed products need licenses". I'm on win 10 Pro 64 bit. The log file can be found here: http://txt.do/1eusu

Thanks for your help in advance. Been struggling for a while now.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1C5t.png)

Comment: Have you asked your Siemens distributor?

Comment: No I haven't asked them yet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to fail at `MSMQ`. Make sure `MSMQ` is enabled,

You can find this under

```
control panel > turn on windows features > MSMQ.
```

Also try to run the installer as administrator (in case you didn't do this already).